# How to swap displays in OSX

Tags: mac, osx-lion, display, display-settings

I have a Macbook Pro running Lion and an external monitor.  I use dual displays.  Is there anyway I can easily switch the displays?  For instance if I have Safari open and sitting in my laptop screen and QuickTime running on the external monitor is there any thing that would allow me to push and a button and switch the displays so that QuickTime is in the laptop  screen and Safari is in the external monitor?

Answer (score 1):

Use mission controller. By default swipe up with 3 fingers (on trackpad).
Then click and drag safari to desktop 2. From now onwards whenever you start safari it opens on external monitor (only when it is connected).

Hope this helps.